# Metric space, countable dense subset and motivation for finite subsets.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Assertion: Every sequence in a metric space $X$ has a subsequence that converges to a point of $X$

> Lemma: Any metric space satisfying 'Assertion' has a countable dense subset.

Proof: Suppose that $X$ is a metric space satisfying 'Assertion' and let $\epsilon>0$ be given. We assert that there exists a finite set $A_\epsilon \subset X$ satisfying

$$
\rho(a,b)\geq \epsilon, \quad {\rm for}\quad a\neq b\quad {\rm in}\quad A_\epsilon,\\
B_\epsilon (x) \cap A_\epsilon \neq \emptyset \quad {\rm for \quad each}\quad x\in X
$$

(proof continues)

I've seen that this statement has to be fulfilled using Zorn's lemma in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455879/metric-spaces-with-countable-dense-subset) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491492/a-problem-on-countable-dense-subset-on-a-metric-space). However, I'm puzzled because my book does not uses this lemma at all and just throws this statement about $A_\epsilon$. Is there a way one can understand and justify the existence of $A_\epsilon$ without resorting to a technicality like Zorn's lemma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the recursive construction of a sequence that has no convergent subsequence. This actually does use a very weak form of the axiom of choice, but what it uses is much weaker than Zorn’s lemma, and the construction is probably a bit more intuitive.

Suppose that no such $A_\epsilon$ exists. Let $x_0\in X$ be arbitrary. Suppose that for some $n$ we have chosen points $x_0,\ldots,x_n\in X$ so that $\rho(x_k,x_\ell)\ge\epsilon$ whenever $0\le k<\ell\le n$; by hypothesis there is a point $x_{n+1}\in X$ such that

$$B_\epsilon(x_{n+1})\cap\{x_0,\ldots,x_n\}=\varnothing\,,$$

so $\rho(x_k,x_{n+1})\ge\epsilon$ for $k=0,\ldots,n$, and we can continue the recursive construction to get a sequence $\langle x_n:n\ge 0\rangle$ in $X$ such that $\rho(x_k,x_\ell)\ge\epsilon$ whenever $0\le k<\ell$. This sequence clearly has no convergent subsequence, contradicting the Assertion.

Comment: Cool. This conditions on the set $A_\epsilon$ seems highly non-obvious. Is there some instace in which they appear that they must be considered "natural" to choose them? Or is it really that after Zorn's lemma that they become obvious?

Comment: @user2820579: That conditions ensures that for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ there is a finite $A_{1/n}\subseteq X$ such that every point of $x$ is within $\frac1n$ some point of $A_{1/n}$. Thus, $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}A_{1/n}$ is countable (because each $A_{1/n}$ is finite) and dense in $X$. Metric spaces that have such a set $A_\epsilon$ for each $\epsilon>0$ are said to be *totally bounded*, and it turns out that a metric space is compact iff it is complete and totally bounded.